# Android SDK: Let user choose picture from gallery or camera?

Tags: android, sdk

In my project I want to let the user pick a picture either from the gallery or take a new one from the camera. Do I need to create my own menu for the user to choose or is there something built into the SDK that does this already?

Comment: I am 99.99% sure you need to write your own menu for this.

Comment: So what you're saying is you're not sure? Ha. Thanks, I was hoping it was built in so it would look the same across all apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below code to put chooser for gallery and Camera together. I really dont know if this will work with startActivityForResult. Give it a try

```
    Intent galleryintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
    galleryintent.setType("image/*");        

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, galleryintent);      
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "title");

    Intent[] intentArray =  {cameraIntent}; 
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
    startActivity(chooser);
```

Comment: I tried using this with startActivityForResult() but for some reason, I am only getting results when I select a picture from galler. In case I take a picture with camera, the result intent is always null.

Comment: How would you tell the difference between receiving result from camera and from gallery?

Comment: When there are multiple applications matching `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`, they are not merged in the same chooser with those matching `EXTRA_INTENT`. Instead, a system item appears in the chooser that triggers the opening of another chooser. Not exactly the best design from the UX point of view.